# Error in Multi valued parameters in SSRS Query

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

When my parameters have multiple values I get the following error:

> The isnull function requires 2 argument(s).

I use the following query:

```
(ISNULL (@Country, N'1') = N'1'
OR Contract.Country IN (@Country)) 

AND (ISNULL(@Season, N'1') = N'1'
OR Contract.Season IN (@Season))
```

This works if the parameters just have one value.

Comment: What do you mean by:  parameters have multiple values?

Comment: For example when the Country parameter contains France and Greece instead of just one of them

Comment: In that case you first need to split in 2. It is not a good idea to put 2 values in 1 variable. You could use a table value parameter with a row for each country

Comment: Think of it like this: (Country IN (@Country)) AND (Season IN (@Season)) but nullable

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CASE` in following:

```
CASE WHEN @Country IS NULL THEN N'1' ELSE @Country END = N'1' 
OR Contract.Country IN (@Country))
```

Or try to use `COALESCE`

```
(COALESCE(@Country, N'1') = N'1'
OR Contract.Country IN (@Country)) 

AND (COALESCE(@Season, N'1') = N'1'
OR Contract.Season IN (@Season))
```

Comment: The syntax seems to work, I don't get any error messages. Thing is: my Query results are off now. It returns records which contain other values than my parameter specifies.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the ISNULL logic in the SELECT part of your dataset, and in your report parameter properties, confirm that both parameters have the checkboxes "Allow multiple values" and "Allow null value" checked.

1. Right-click the parameter in the Parameters list to open the Report Parameter Proprerties dialog.
2. From the General page, check off the "Allow multiple values" box.
3. From the General page, check off the "Allow null value" box.
4. Change the field in the SELECT list to use ISNULL(@Country, N'1')

Answer (score 0):

It was actually easier than I would have thought, I used the following query:

(Contract.Season IN (@Season)) and allow null values on the parameter in ssrs.

Thanks for all the replies.